# Cannot find "has_antenna_diversity_support"

Tags: wireless

I have a HP Pavilion dm1 and I cannot get the wireless to work.

I have found may tutorials on how to fix this, but they require changing *HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT* to *HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT=y*.
I cannot find *HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT* in the list that is generated when I enter `vi os/linux/config.mk`.

I followed [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1776880.html) making changes to version number as what was in the package was not the same version. It was 3.5.0.3 instead of 2.4.0.4.

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the version is **2**.5.0.3; that's the latest version at Realtek's site.

```
#Support Antenna Diversity
HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT=n
```

This is located at lines 114-115 of os/linux/config.mk.